# How to let javamail support http proxy

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, http-proxy

I found that javamail only support socks. Is there any solution I can use to support http proxy?

```
public class MailConnectionTest {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws MessagingException {
   Properties props = MailConnectionTest.getProperties();
   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
   String protocol = "pop3";
   String host = "pop.163.com";
   String username = "email username";
   String password = "1Qaz2wsx3edc&";
   Store store = session.getStore(protocol);
   store.connect(host, username, password);
   System.out.println("Success");
}
private static Properties getProperties() {
 Properties props = System.getProperties();
 props.put("mail.debug", "false");
 // Proxy
 props.put("proxySet", "true");
 props.put("http.proxyHost", "proxyAdderss");
 props.put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
 return props;
}
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. HTTP proxies are for HTTP. JavaMail uses SMTP and POP3 and IMAP. Not HTTP.

Comment: That's my point. Do you mean that it is no way to use http proxy for javamail. So, does javamial can use socks proxy? then how to use?

Comment: why do you want that? SMTP should be good, right?

Comment: I can not get you. SMTP is a protocol to send email. But my point is using POP3 or IMAP to receive mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the JavaMail FAQ:

- [How do I configure JavaMail to work through my proxy server?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy)

> ...  Without such a SOCKS server, if you want to use JavaMail to access mail servers outside the firewall indirectly, you might be able to use a program such as [Corkscrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corkscrew_%28program%29) or [connect](https://bitbucket.org/gotoh/connect/wiki/Home) to tunnel TCP connections through an HTTP proxy server. JavaMail does not support direct access through an HTTP proxy web server.

Comment: Thank you. I know what you mean. I need a program or tool to make the connections through a HTTP proxy sever. So how can I integrate my Java code with Corkscrew or connect as a single Java class? I mean that is there a jar I can use to make it simple.

Comment: No.  After setting up one of these other programs, you need to configure JavaMail to use them as a SOCKS proxy server.

Comment: I drew a flow. JavaMail -> SOCKS proxy -> Corkscrew or connect -> http proxy server. Is it right? So Corkscrew or connect is like a adapter that can convert socks proxy to http proxy?

Comment: Yes, it **is** a SOCKS proxy, there's no separate SOCKS proxy in the flow.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know it's an old topic, but my question may be relevant for others: Does JavaMail support NonProxyHosts settings? I could not find that in the doc.

Comment: No.  Just use a different Session with different proxy configuration when connecting to a different server that doesn't require a proxy connection.

Answer (score 6):

As per the latest release of Javamail API 1.6.2 , JavaMail supports accessing mail servers through a web proxy server and also authenticating to the proxy server. Please see my code below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

public class ReadMailProxy {

    public static void receiveMail(String userName, String password) {
        try {
            String proxyIP = "124.124.124.14";
            String proxyPort = "4154";
            String proxyUser = "test";
            String proxyPassword = "test123";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.proxy.host", proxyIP);
            prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.proxy.port", proxyPort);
            prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.proxy.user", proxyUser);
            prop.setProperty("mail.imaps.proxy.password", proxyPassword);

            Session eSession = Session.getInstance(prop);

            Store eStore = eSession.getStore("imaps");
            eStore.connect("imap.mail.yahoo.com", userName, password);

            Folder eFolder = eStore.getFolder("Inbox");
            eFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            Message messages[] = eFolder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
            System.out.println(messages.length);
            for (int i = messages.length - 3; i < messages.length - 2; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                System.out.println("Email Number::" + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Subject::" + message.getSubject());
                System.out.println("From::" + message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Date::" + message.getSentDate());

                try {
                    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

                    for (int x = 0; x < multipart.getCount(); x++) {
                        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(x);

                        String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

                        if (disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT))) {
                            System.out.println("Mail have some attachment : ");

                            DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                            System.out.println("file name : " + handler.getName());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(bodyPart.getContent());
                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Content: " + message.getContent().toString());
                }

                message.setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);
            }
            eFolder.close(true);
            eStore.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        receiveMail("umesh@yahoo.com", "test123");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is an IP required or does any hostname work? Many corporate proxies have a DNS name.

Comment: Hostname should work. I haven't tried that yet. But based on my understanding it should work

Answer (score 2):

javamail api 1.6 supports web server proxy

set these properties

`mail.protocol.proxy.host`

`mail.protocol.proxy.port`

for example to use smtp you can set as below
for **smtp** set as

`mail.smtp.proxy.host`

`mail.smtp.proxy.port`

Answer (score 0):

The implementation only support basic authentication for web proxy. You can find the source code in  com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.

Since javamail support NTLM authentication already, it is not hard to support NTLM authentication for web proxy.