# How to get gmail inbox messages through proxy with java

Tags: java, proxy, jakarta-mail

I use this code to access gmail inbox:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties( ));
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993, email, password);
    inbox = store.getFolder( "INBOX" );
    inbox.open( Folder.READ_ONLY );
```

But behind proxy this code throws timeout exceptions.
Any ideas?

Tried this code but it didn't work:

```
 Properties properties = new Properties( );
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.proxy.host", "https://proxy.some.com");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.proxy.port", "912");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993, email, password);
    inbox = store.getFolder( "INBOX" );
    inbox.open( Folder.READ_ONLY );
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278073/how-to-let-javamail-support-http-proxy

Comment: didn't work, please see my update